# Objective C, Difference between defining private variables with @private and defining them with class extension?

Tags: objective-c, private-members

I wonder the difference between defining private variables in the .h file using the key word @private and defining them in the .m file using the class extension?

Thanks.

Comment: They control different aspects. `@private` is an access modifier (it makes the variable completely unusable using the `->` operator *even if it is visible*). In contrast, the hiding-behind-class-extension is just a programming technique of which the aim is that the user of the class doesn't even know about the existence of a particular ivar.

Comment: You don't even have to hide it in a class extension anymore.  iVars defined in the `@implementation {}`  directive work as well.

Comment: @CodaFi That's what is called a "class extension". You are confusing class extensions and categories.

Comment: @H2C03 Last I checked, it was just called an @implementation directive.  A class extension is an anonymous category (i.e. `SomeClass ()`).  What I meant is that `@implementation { id var;}` works better than a category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iVar declared in the implementation are implicitly hidden (effectively private) and the visibility cannot be changed - @public, @protected and @private do not produce compiler errors (with the current Clang at least) but are ignored.

Comment: \@public, \@protected and \@private are ignored? This cannot be true. @Ishu

Comment: @Fei Zhu, What you understand with this sentence. i am saying these keyword having their effect but your ivar are visible in other classes.